# Application.Match not searching the variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using `Application.Match(number, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), 0)` to find the row number where there is a `number` value...

`number` is a textfield, where the user puts a number and i search it thru the sheet.

I've used this a hundred times, and use it normally as i speak.

The problem is that with this particular textfield, it won't search !
When i replace the textfield name with a real number, putting like:

`Application.Match(8565, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), 0)`

It works! But with the textfield it wont...

I've already msgboxed the textfield values to check if it's right and it is

I've tried `number.text`, `number.value`, and even a function that get only the numbers from a string...

The msgbox gives me the correct number, but it wont search !

What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the textfield was giving me a String, even if only numbers were being typed...

So, the Application.Match was looking for a string when the cell values were numbers...

Solved by using the function val() to change string to double.